# Comparing two numpy arrays and replacing value of one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, A and B. A contains dtypes = ['ID','Value','Type'] and B contains dtypes = ['ID','Value'].

Essentially I want to replace the 'Value' in A with the value in 'B' but only for the 'ID's that are in both (so the IDs in B also in A).

```
A = array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0.785, 0.985, 0.8562, 0.9652, 0.664, 0.962, 0.872],['sio', 'sco', 'sio', 'sco', 'sio', 'sco', 'sio']])
B = array([[1,2,3],[0.85,0.4585,0.8436]])
```

The lengths of A and B are likely to differ in size and hence the need to map values rather than assume the ids are all in the same order.

What is the fastest way of doing this?

Comment: Please add a sample case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps, I used `OrderedDict` just in case your data is not only ordered ints:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

A = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0.785,0.985,0.8562,0.9652,0.664,0.962,0.872],[' sio', 'sco', 'sio', 'sco', 'sio', 'sco','sio']]
B = [[1,2,3],[0.85,0.4585,0.8436]]

a = OrderedDict(zip(*A[:2]))
b = dict(zip(*B))

c = OrderedDict([(k, b[k] if k in b else v) for k, v in a.items()])

A = [c.keys(), c.values(), A[2]]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 [0.85, 0.4585, 0.8436, 0.9652, 0.664, 0.962, 0.872],
 [' sio', 'sco', 'sio', 'sco', 'sio', 'sco', 'sio']]
```

Comment: Thanks the answer was required for potentially unordered arrays. If I may extend the question, how would this work if the 'value' dtype didn't exist in A, and I wanted to map the column 'value' of B to A based on the 'ID' (set to 0 if doesn't exist)?

Comment: This takes values of A and if they exist in B replaces their value in corresponding index. I add code for adding values of B that do not exist in A but from your data you would also need information for third array with `'sio'` and `'sco'`

Answer (score 0):

Is this sufficiently fast for you?

```
import numpy

A = numpy.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0.785,0.985,0.8562,0.9652,0.664,0.962,0.872],[' sio', 'sco', 'sio', 'sco', 'sio', 'sco','sio']])
B = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[0.85,0.4585,0.8436]])
for i, x in enumerate(A[0]):
    if x in str(B[0]):
        A[1,i] = B[1,i]
print A
```

Ouput:

```
[['1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7']
 ['0.85' '0.4585' '0.8436' '0.9652' '0.664' '0.962' '0.872']
 [' sio' 'sco' 'sio' 'sco' 'sio' 'sco' 'sio']]
```